# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab'

Tags: pip, reportlab

I have tried:
pip install report lab
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall reportlab;

but still reportlab cannot be recognised with pycharm but it's already imported via PIP as below

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command instead:

```
pip install reportlab
```

Also if you are using an "virtual enviroment" then that is causing the problem.
If you are using pycharm then,
Use this command in pycharm's terminal:

```
pip install reportlab
```

Comment: Dear @leftclik, I had tried the same and it's not working.